# Custom operators error when passing parameters c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, operators

I'm building custom operators and im having problems when passing parameters to them.

For example

```
class test{
     public:
        test operator[](vector <string> s){
            test a;
            return a;
         }
};
```

Now if I wanted in my main program to do something like this

```
 int main(){

    test d;
    vector<string> s;
    s.push_back("bla");
    d[s];
 }
```

I get a bunch of errors. Is it because I need to have const somewhere or I don't know.

Also I have built in a custom operator for printing out the class test ( << operator ). Now I don't get compile error when calling d[s] in main program but I get compile error when calling cout<< d[s] in main program. The operator << is working because I tested it with simple cout<< d

Comment: Please post the errors.

Comment: Again, the code you've posted is [fine](http://ideone.com/dlAHE6). Could you post the exact code that fails, and the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Code working fine using gcc compiler.

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class test{
     public:
        test operator[](vector <string> s){
            test a;
            return a;
         }
};

int main(){

    test d;
    vector<string> s;
    s.push_back("bla");
    d[s];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return test;
```

`test` is a type. You can't return a type. Perhaps you meant:

```
return a;
```

But then you have another problem because you're returning a reference to a local variable. The object `a` will be destroyed when the function returns (because that is its scope) and so the reference will be left dangling.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the errors that other folk have already pointed out (dangling reference, returning a type rather than the value), note that if you intend to override [], you should also consider overriding the pointer deference operator (unary *) too as many folk use them interchangeably.